# React Typescript Component with Multiple Prop Types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-typescript

I have the following component where it will take a config object, which can either be an object which contains a `name` property which will be a string, or a boolean in the case that the config object has not been populated yet.

```
type Config = {
  name: string;
};

const Widget = ({ config }: { config: Config } | boolean) => {
  return <p>{config.name}</p>;
};

export default function App() {
  let config = {
    name: "Bob"
  };
  // config = false;
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Name:</h1>
      {config && <Widget config={config} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

TS is complaining that `Property 'config' does not exist on type 'boolean | { config: Config; }'.ts(2339)`. What is the correct TS fix? It seems that annotating it with type `any` does seem to work, but I'd obviously like to avoid this.

Comment: It should be `Widget = ({ config }: { config: Config | boolean })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is related to the `boolean`.

In making the parameter `{ config }: { config: Config } | boolean`, you're saying:

- the parameter may be `{ config: Config }`, or
- the parameter may be `boolean`.

With a JSX component, the parameter is the props in the form of an object. In what case will JSX props be boolean? Never. So that's likely the error.

Change it to:

```
const Widget = ({ config }: { config: Config }) => {
  return <p>{config.name}</p>;
};
```

or if you want config to be optional:

```
const Widget = ({ config }: { config?: Config }) => {
  return <p>{config.name}</p>;
};
```

or if you want config to sometimes accept `true`/`false` for some reason (you probably don't want to do this):

```
const Widget = ({ config }: { config: Config | boolean }) => {
  return <p>{config.name}</p>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only solve your problem using `null`.  Your code would look like this:

```
   type Config = {
        name: string
    }
    
    const Widget = (config : Config | null) => {
    
        if(!config) {
           return !--- not populated config code
        } else {
            <p>{config.name}</p>;
        }
    };
```